# How can I access data attributes for a class in my  MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following class:

```
namespace Storage.Models
{
    public class AdminDetail
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Display Order")]
        public string Order { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
    }
```

I had some advice and I set up the following as the model in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminDetail>
```

Is it possible for me to somehow reference attributes of my AdminDetail class such as [DisplayName("Display Order")]. What I would like to do is something like this to show column labels for the first row of my table grid.

```
<div>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Order)</div>
```

But I am not sure how to do this as my model is of a collection and not a single instance.

Here's the code I use to generate data for the view:

```
        IEnumerable<AdminDetail> details = null;
        IList<AdminDetail> detailsList = null;
        details = from t in _table
                      select new AdminDetail
                      {
                          PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
                          RowKey = t.RowKey,
                          Title = t.Title,
                          Status = t.Status,
                          Type = t.Type,
                          Level = t.Level,
                          Order = t.Order
                      };
            #endregion
            detailsList = details
                .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                .ThenBy(item => item.Title)
                .Select((t, index) => new AdminDetail() { 
                    PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey, 
                    RowKey = t.RowKey, 
                    Title = t.Title, 
                    Status = t.Status, 
                    Type = t.Type, 
                    Level = t.Level, 
                    Order = t.Order, 
                    Row = index + 1 })
                 .ToList();

 return detailsList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminDetail>

@foreach (var detail in Model)
{
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(x => detail.Order)</div>
}
```

or if you are using an editor template which is what I would recommend:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminDetail>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then inside the display template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AdminDetail.cshtml`):

```
@model AdminDetail
<div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order)</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

You could use `IList<AdminDetail>` as your view model type which will give you index access to elements and you could fetch the metadata like this:

```
@model IList<AdminDetail>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Order)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and inside the display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/AdminDetail.cshtml`):

```
@model AdminDetail
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Order)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But the problem is that the labels are for headings to all of the rows in the grid so they would need to be outside of the foreach loop as the labels only appear once at the top of the grid.

Comment: :3, just when I think I know enough about MVC you come in and always share something awesome. I love reading your answers!

Comment: @Melissa, oh you are using a grid? Right. Your view model is not adapted for this view then.

Comment: HYes it's a grid. How could I make a view model that would be suitable. It's 99% okay as it gives all the rows. Just hard to do the column headings. Should I make a viewModel that passes both the AdminDetail and IEnumberable<AdminDetail> ?

Comment: @Melissa, how are you generating this grid? Show us some code first.

Comment: Hello Darin, The grid is an HTML table outside of the foreach and then HTML rows and columns inside the foreach. I generate the source for the grid from a LINQ select statement. It's a simple data grid with one row of the table being shown as one row on the grid.

Comment: @Darin, I tried your suggestion but it gives the following:Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Storage.Models.AdminDetail>

Comment: @Melissa, did you notice that I used `@model IList<AdminDetail>` instead of `@model IEnumerable<AdminDetail>`?

Comment: Sorry Darin. I missed that. Your answer works perfectly as always. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to make a table, and just need the label one time, just instantiate a new item of the class you want and call the `LabelFor` methods on it.

```
@{ var labelModel = new AdminDetail; }
@Html.LabelFor(model => labelModel.Order);
```

It's a bit of a hacky way to do it, but it will prevent you from writing your own reflection and it won't tie the label in the header to a specific input on the page.